# How many subsets have this property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of subsets of $$S= \left\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\right\}$$ with exactly $5$ elements including $3$ or $4$ but not both.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the network! Let's use inclusion and exclusion - in particular, we will count the number of subsets that contain at least one of $3$ or $4$, then count the number subsets containing both $3$ and $4$, then subtract the two to obtain the answer.

The number of subsets containing at least one of $3$ or $4$ is $2 \cdot {9 \choose 4}$ ($2$ ways to choose one of $3$ or $4$, $9 \choose 4$ ways to choose the other $4$ numbers). The number of subsets containing $\bf{both}$ will be $1 \cdot {8 \choose 3}$ (1 way to choose both $3$ and $4$, and $8 \choose 3$ ways to choose the other three arbitrary numbers). However, we have double counted the number of subsets that contain both a $3$ and a $4$. Therefore, we need to subtract this value twice to obtain the result of $\boxed{140}$ possible ways.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. It should be $140$.

Comment: You're right. This is the union of the two.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $N_k$ be the number of $5-$subsets of $S$ that contain the element $k$. Then you want 
$$N_3+N_4-2N_{34},$$
where $N_{34}$ is the number of $5-$subsets of $S$ that contain both $3$ and $4$.

To get $N_3$, you already have element $3$ inside such sets. So you can only choose 
$4$ elements from $S-\{3\}$ to form a subset of size $5$ that contains the element $3$. So essentially you are choosing a subset of size $4$ from $S-\{3\}$. This can be done in $\binom{9}{4}$ ways.

So the final count will be 
$$\binom{9}{4}+\binom{9}{4}-2\binom{8}{3}=126+126-112=\color{red}{140}.$$

**Second method:**
Let $A$ be a $5-$subset of $S$ that contains $3$ but not $4$. So essentially you have to now pick four elements from $S-\{3,4\}$ to form the subset $A$. This can be done in  $\binom{8}{4}=70$ ways. You can do the same when $4$ is in the set and $3$ is not. So a total of $140$ ways,

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be the number of ways to get $4$ elements out of $8$ (excluding $3$ and $4$) and then grouping them with either $3$ or $4$.

$n = \binom{8}{4} \cdot 2 = 70\cdot 2  = 140$